# Pandas dataFrame cause crash because of memory limit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recommendation-engine

I'm a beginner in python and recommendation sytstems.

I want to implement a recommendation system in python with this tutorial:

https://towardsdatascience.com/solving-business-usecases-by-recommender-system-using-lightfm-4ba7b3ac8e62

But when I run the project, it crashes because of memory limit:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 71.5 GiB for an array with shape (162541, 59047) and data type float64
```

I know that this is because of dataFrame size (100k rows, 25 columns).
the code that generates this dataFrame:

```
def create_interaction_matrix(df, user_col, item_col, rating_col, norm=False, threshold=None):
'''
Function to create an interaction matrix dataframe from transactional type interactions
Required Input -
    - df = Pandas DataFrame containing user-item interactions
    - user_col = column name containing user's identifier
    - item_col = column name containing item's identifier
    - rating col = column name containing user feedback on interaction with a given item
    - norm (optional) = True if a normalization of ratings is needed
    - threshold (required if norm = True) = value above which the rating is favorable
Expected output - 
    - Pandas dataframe with user-item interactions ready to be fed in a recommendation algorithm
'''
interactions = df.groupby([user_col, item_col])[rating_col] \
    .sum().unstack().reset_index(). \
    fillna(0).set_index(user_col)
if norm:
    interactions = interactions.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x > threshold else 0)
return interactions
```

But I have no idea to solve it.

- Is there any alternative dataType or anything to pandas.dataFrame that uses less RAM (at least less than 4GB)? Or any solution for generating smaller dataFrame?
- Is there any solution for save/load dataFrame in Hard Drive? or in memory with less RAM usage?

Comment: Although the author of this article did not use this, but have you tried to [chunk your data](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-and-how-to-use-pandas-with-large-data-9594dda2ea4c#:~:text=Pandas%20is%20very%20efficient%20with,performance%20is%20rarely%20a%20concern.) ?

Comment: Use sparse matrix or sparse dataframe. So do not `unstack` and use the long form.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks. can you suggest any tutorial about it?

Comment: [Sparse data structure](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html) and [Scipy sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).